# Issue with Podio's ASP.NET sample application authoring

Tags: podio

Whenever I run the [Podio ASP.NET Sample Application](https://github.com/podio/asp-net-sample), it displays me the 'Authentication' page asking for either my Podio credentials or to choose the "Server side flow" with "Sign in to Podio"-button. However, once I try to authenticate with either method, Visual Studio prompts me with a "SqlException was unhandled by user code - An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in NPoco.dll but was not handled in user code" warning ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc3R0.png)), referring to line 20 on PodioOAuthData.cs. I've followed the instructions on the GitHub readme page but I can't get it to work. Any idea if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the readme is a little light on details when it comes to an out-of-the-box experience.

You actually need a running SQL server somewhere. And then edit `PodioAspNetSample/Web.config` (https://github.com/podio/asp-net-sample/blob/master/PodioAspNetSample/Web.config#L22) to contain the right connection string.

Good luck.

Comment: Ah, right. Thought there was more to it than the readme lets on. Thanks for the reply.